# Problems with importing variables from python script to python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I tried to import the variables from my `Leo.py` file to my `Max.py` file like this: Leo.py:

```
> import tkinter import time import os import Max from tkinter import *
> from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox from selenium import
> webdriver from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By from
> selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait from
> selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC from
> selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys from
> selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains from time
> import sleep from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
> 
> 
>     def combined_func(*args, **kwargs):
>         for f in funcs:
>             f(*args, **kwargs)
>     return combined_func
> 
> def Name():
>     global Name
>     Name = t.get()
> 
> def Message():
>     global Message
>     Message = t2.get()
> 
> def Number():
>     global Number
>     Number_string = t3.get()
>     Number = int(Number_string)
> 
> def Delay():
>     global Delay
>     Delay_string= t4.get()
>     Delay = int(Delay_string)
> 
> def close_window ():
>     root.destroy()
> 
> root = Tk()
> 
> w = Label(width = '40', height = '0') w.pack()
> 
> t = Entry(root) t.insert(INSERT, 'Insert Name') t.pack()
> 
> t2 = Entry(root) t2.insert(INSERT, 'Insert Messsage') t2.pack()
> 
> t3 = Entry(root) t3.insert(INSERT, 'Insert Number') t3.pack()
> 
> t4 = Entry(root) t4.insert(INSERT, 'Insert Delay') t4.pack()
> 
> b = Button(root, text='Run', command = combine_funcs(Name, Message,
> Number, Delay, close_window)) b.pack()
> 
> mainloop()
> 
> os.system('Max.py')
> 
> browser = webdriver.Chrome() browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
> wait = browser.implicitly_wait(3)
> 
> time.sleep(10)
> 
> N=1 Spam = 1
> 
> actions = ActionChains(browser) for _ in range(N):
>     actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB) actions.perform()
> 
> for _ in range(N):
>     actions = actions.send_keys(Name) actions.perform()
> 
> time.sleep(2)
> 
> for _ in range(N):
>     actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.TAB) actions.perform()
> 
> time.sleep(2)
> 
> for _ in range(N):
>     actions = actions.send_keys(Keys.ENTER) actions.perform()
> 
> time.sleep(2)
> 
> while (Spam <= Number):
> 
>     for _ in range (1):
>         actions = actions.send_keys(Message, Keys.ENTER)
>     actions.perform()
>     Spam += 1
>     actions.reset_actions()
>     time.sleep(Delay)
```

Max.py:

```
> import Leo from Leo import * import tkinter from tkinter import *
> 
> root = Tk()
> 
> count = Label(root, text = Number)
> 
> mainloop()
```

But running the `Leo.py` scrip always gives me the error

> NameError: name 'Number' is not defined

How do I use the variables from `Leo.py` in `Max.py`?

Thanks for any help in advance:)

Comment: Please make an attempt to format your code.

Comment: Please excuse my messy code; I am very new to this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Leo.number otherwise python thinks you're referring to a local variable. The variables in Leo that you want to use outside of Leo also need to be declared as global or they won't be accessible outside the scope of Leo.

Hope this helps

Gareth

Comment: If I am not mistake, the variable Number is declared as global, but upon running the script with Leo.Number instead of Number in the Max.py file, I get the message "module 'Leo' has no attribute 'Number'"